# How to get the Cost values algorithm analysis

Tags: algorithm

Recently I've been learning algorithm design, and it comes to part where to get the order of growth(if I'm mistaken). I'd seen from the Insertion Sort to the running time which is to calculate the algorithm perhaps it's known as worst case. The thing is I couldn't understand to find the n. For example:

```
print "Hello"
for i = 0 to n:
  print i * 1
print "end of program"
```

So, if I want to calculate the runtime, how I suppose to get the n and calculate T(n). The problem I believe that I don't understand the basic. I've googled and nothing satisfied me, and also I couldn't understand.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

n is a measure for the size of the input of an algorithm.

For example sorting:
n is the number of elements to sort

For example insert an element in a list:
n is the number of elements already in the list

Answer (score 0):

'N' is the count of objects/elements/entities for which one's algorithm will run. **The performance of the algorithm depends on how it performs when this 'N' changes**.
Performance can be measured by execution time (no. of operations performed) i.e time taken by the algorithm to run fully over a certain set of input  and memory usage.

In order to quantify an algorithm's performance we have complexity Analysis.
In majority of the cases we use Big-O complexity which is the worst case complexity bound for a certain algorithm.

In case of sorting algorithms like Insertion sort we have `O(N^2)` complexity which basically means the execution time or no. of operations performed  by algorithm will increase quite quadratiacally with sufficient large values of N.

Example graph for no. of operations performed by algorithm with complexity of O(N^2)
  [image]

Y-Axis :  No. of operations performed by algorithm

X-Axis : Input Size to the algorithm